# No sound from speakers in monitor

Tags: sound, 18.04, speakers

The speakers in my monitor show up and I'm able to use the volume slider on them but that doesn't do anything. It's not muted and they work fine in windows 10 (dual boot).

My headphones also show up and they DO work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried checking the options in System Settings>Sound>Output??

Comment: @PRATAP Yes, as I said it shows up. Clicking test speakers produces no sound and it is definitely not muted.

Comment: Can you share the model number of your monitor? Is it connected via hdmi or dvi or vga?

Comment: It's connected via DVI-D and has a separate cable for audio connected. I'm unsure about the model number, though it could be ASUS VP228T.

Comment: Hi, I am searching what could be the reason. Can u send me Pic when you are at settings, sound, output screen?

Comment: @Krishi did you found solution for it?

Comment: @PRATAP did you found solution for it? I am also facing the same issue. I am using Dell SE2417HG monitor

Comment: @JaydipKalkani Hi, no.. can you share a image like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmjcu.png

Comment: @PRATAP Sure. Check this (http://prntscr.com/mnls4u)

Comment: @JaydipKalkani Ok, thats nice pic...can you eloborate.. Dell SE2417HG monitor is used to connect laptop or Desktop and via VGA.. DVI..or HDMI Cable..

Comment: @PRATAP It's used to connect desktop and i used VGA for connection.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani i have gone through the manual of Dell SE2417HG and found that the port is for OUT not In.. means this monitor does not have speakers. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFmus.png Point No.2 is important to note.

Comment: means if you watch a movie by connecting USB to this monitor.. then you can connect external speakers with AUX 3.5mm Jack Cable and hear the sound.